# Mac receiving ICMP requests but not sending any replies

Tags: macos, firewall, ping, icmp, pf

Why could my osx machine be receiving ICMP requests (that I'm sending), but not returning any replies?

```
$ sudo tcpdump -nni any icmp
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type PKTAP (Packet Tap), capture size 65535 bytes
07:59:37.858801 IP 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 1941, seq 6, length 64
07:59:38.882701 IP 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 1941, seq 7, length 64
07:59:39.905794 IP 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 1941, seq 8, length 64
07:59:40.928857 IP 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 1941, seq 9, length 64
07:59:41.953113 IP 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 1941, seq 10, length 64
07:59:42.975912 IP 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 1941, seq 11, length 64
```

My ping requests:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.5
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.5 ping statistics ---
480 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 490401ms
```

Firewall is disabled and these are my port forwarding settings:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
pass on lo0
pass on en0
pass on utun0
```